# Validate first 2 characters of a textfield follwed by 4 int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need validation in a text box that when I enter some value in the text box, the first two characters should be characters only, then it allows only followed by 4 ints.

i wrote code like below:

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(Txtvalue.Text, "^[A-Za-z]{2}d{4}.+$"))
```

It shows error only. not validate properly.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @John he is matching abddddx instead of ab1234x

Comment: @Robin That isn't anywhere in the question. Questions are expected to provide this information. The question sets out what OP wants, what OP has done, but doesn't declare the error they are receiving, or how it doesn't validate their text properly.

Comment: @John you are completely right there and in most cases, I wouldn't have tried to infer anything from the question without further information but in this case, I felt like it was possible to implicitly extract this information from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an editor (e.g. [regex101](http://regex101.com) ) for regexes to debug them while writing. 
One problem I see on your regex is that you are matching d literally.

I suppose you meant to write `\d` to match digits.

So `^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{4}.+$` should work.

Another thing I am suspecting is that you don't want the `+` quantifier as this will prevent `ab1234` from being matched when it is not followed at least by a single character. To solve this use the `*` quantifier instead.

Comment: `\ ` in c# is an escape character so you might want to escape it by writing `\\d` or use auto escaping by defining the string with an @ in front ( `@"^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{4}.+$"` )